# How can I configure my package.json so that certain packages will only install on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, package.json

I am using the "msnodesqlv8": "0.2.3" npm package for my app to run some MSSQL scripts on Windows, but on Mac I can't install all of the other packages due to this error:

```
Macbook-Pro jeremy$ npm install
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/jeremy/.nvm/versions/node/v6.1.0/bin/node" "/Users/jeremy/.nvm/versions/node/v6.1.0/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: msnodesqlv8@0.2.3
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jeremy/code/lyfeboat/mitchell-sql-feathers/npm-debug.log
```

Is there a way to configure my package.json such that this package will be ignored on all non-windows systems?

Comment: A workaround is of course to remove that package from package.json, save, and run npm install. Ideally though, I'd be able to fix my package.json so this workaround is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but I was able to get the desired behavior using the optionalDependencies property in package.json.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies

Here is the format I used:

```
...
"optionalDependencies": {
  "msnodesqlv8": "0.2.3"
},
...
```

Output as expected:

```
Macbook-Pro jeremy$ npm install
...
*installed other packages normally*
...
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency //msnodesqlv8:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: msnodesqlv8@0.2.3
```